# How to add a horizontal line after second row?

Tags: html, css

Here is my code: [Codepen](http://codepen.io/nikhilrajnair/pen/QyBqPa). I need to add a horizontal line after the second row. How can I do it as shown in the image:

[image]

```
<table class="tg1">
    <tr>
        <th class="tg-031e1" colspan="4">Email</th>
        <th class="tg-yw4l1" colspan="4">Order Details</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="tg-yw4l1" colspan="4">
            <p style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #555555; font-size: 14px; padding: 5px ;">xyz@gmail.com<br>
            Telephone: 657676767676<br>
            IP Address: 102.364.134.93<br>
            Order Status: Pending</p>
        </td>
        <td class="tg-yw41l" colspan="4">
            <p style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #555555; font-size: 14px; padding: 5px ;">xxx@gmail.com<br>
            Telephone: 657676767676<br>
            IP Address:000.000.00.01<br>
            Order Status: Pending</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this snippet:**

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
tbody > tr:first-child {
    border-bottom: 4px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<table class="tg1">
      <tr>
        <th class="tg-031e1" colspan="4">Email</th>
        <th class="tg-yw4l1" colspan="4">Order Details</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="tg-yw4l1" colspan="4">
            <p style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #555555; font-size: 14px; padding: 5px ;">xyz@gmail.com<br>
                                Telephone: 657676767676<br>
                                IP Address: 102.364.134.93<br>
                                Order Status: Pending</p>
        </td>
        <td class="tg-yw41l" colspan="4">
            <p style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #555555; font-size: 14px; padding: 5px ;">xxx@gmail.com<br>
                                Telephone: 657676767676<br>
                                IP Address:000.000.00.01<br>
                                Order Status: Pending</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

just edit a new row to your table with colspan="8" and then insert for example a horizontal ruler

```html
<table class="tg1">
      <tr>
        <th class="tg-031e1" colspan="4">Email</th>
        <th class="tg-yw4l1" colspan="4">Order Details</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="8"><hr></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="tg-yw4l1" colspan="4">
            <p style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #555555; font-size: 14px; padding: 5px ;">xyz@gmail.com<br>
                                Telephone: 657676767676<br>
                                IP Address: 102.364.134.93<br>
                                Order Status: Pending</p>
        </td>
        <td class="tg-yw41l" colspan="4">
            <p style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #555555; font-size: 14px; padding: 5px ;">xxx@gmail.com<br>
                                Telephone: 657676767676<br>
                                IP Address:000.000.00.01<br>
                                Order Status: Pending</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is always good to make use of the best practices. For example: `th` should be placed inside `thead` and the contents inside `tbody`. One more thing, since the same styles are getting used, its better to apply via css. Please find below the code:

**HTML**

```
   <table class="tg1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="tg-031e1" colspan="4">Email</th>
                <th class="tg-yw4l1" colspan="4">Order Details</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="tg-yw4l1" colspan="4">
                    <p>
                        xyz@gmail.com<br>
                        Telephone: 657676767676<br>
                        IP Address: 102.364.134.93<br>
                        Order Status: Pending
                    </p>
                </td>
                <td class="tg-yw41l" colspan="4">
                    <p>
                        xxx@gmail.com<br>
                        Telephone: 657676767676<br>
                        IP Address:000.000.00.01<br>
                        Order Status: Pending
                    </p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

**CSS**

```
.tg1 {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

    .tg1 thead {
        border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
    }

    .tg1 tbody p {
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        color: #555555;
        font-size: 14px;
        padding: 5px;
    }
```